# Change a symfony plugin's model

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm using the symfony plugin "[sfMultipleAjaxUploadGalleryPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfMultipleAjaxUploadGalleryPlugin)", and I would like to modify it's model.

I want to change the "Photo" class, removing the field "title" and adding the fields "description_fr" and "description_en".

I've made the changes in phpmyadmin, and, in the plugin, I've edited the schema, and the models, filters, and forms to reflect the changes.

I've emptied the cache, but I get doctrine errors concerning the new fields. This plugin is like the admin generator, it extends the class "autosomething", created in the cache at runtime.

Any ideas ? Where else could the photos' model be defined ?

Since it is in the plugins/ folder, I can't just recreate everything using the command-line client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid the changes in phpMyAdmin are completely useless, since once you will do a build everything in the database will be managed by symfony itself.
You should first make the wanted changes in the schema, then adjust the relevant classes

in the model 
`sf_plugin_dir/sfMultipleAjaxUploadGalleryPlugin/lib/model/doctrine/Photo.class.php` and `sf_plugin_dir/sfMultipleAjaxUploadGalleryPlugin/lib/model/doctrine/PhotoTable.class.php`,

in the form `sf_plugin_dir/sfMultipleAjaxUploadGalleryPlugin/lib/form/doctrine/PhotoForm.class.php`

and possibly in the filters `sf_plugin_dir/sfMultipleAjaxUploadGalleryPlugin/lib/filter/doctrine/PhotoFormFilter.class.php`

and check also possible helpers
in `sf_plugin_dir/sfMultipleAjaxUploadGalleryPlugin/lib/helper/`.

Then you should check every action/template using the changed Photo model (if any) and adjust accordingly.

Finally empty the cache

```
symfony cc
```

be sure the changes are reflected in all the model classes (not really important, but still)

```
symfony doctrine:clean
```

rebuild everything

```
symfony doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation
```

it should work now.